# How to install Glodroid for the Pinephone onto a microSD Card

Tags: linux, shell-script, system-installation, android, phone

How to install Glodroid 0.6.1 onto a microSD card?

A microSD card allows Glodroid to be tried out *without* permanently writing to the PinePhone, ie, its EMMC.

A slot-in-to-try-and-slot-out-when-done solution.

But Glodroid 0.6.1, the latest version as of writing, does not work.

Someone reported succeeding by installing to the PinePhone's EMMC though (https://github.com/GloDroid/glodroid_manifest/issues/39).

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found a solution that you want to share. However, as a Q&A site, "Question" should be used to explain the issue, while "Answers" is the place to provide the solutions. Consider posting it as a proper answer instead, since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### *Glodroid 0.7 and 0.5.1 Definately Work !*

*Dedicated to those frustrated souls...*

Comments:

- *updated 3 Dec 21*
- For Glodroid 0.7, it is the same process but it might require factory reset. It seems Glodroid does store on the PinePhone some persistent configuration settings. Does not appear to impare those already stored on the EMMC atleast for the KDE Community edition. Factory reset seems to affect only Glodroid
- For Glodroid 0.6.1, it is the same process but did not work for me. There was just a continuous red light and 'dead' black screen
- USB tethering did not work for me. So, USB debugging didn't also for both versions
- This is not to install permanently on the phone, but to the microSD card. This will make a bootable card for the PinePhone which - when *and* as long as it is slotted in - allows changing the OS at boot to that of the microSD card's
- This is for *trying out* Android (12 & 11 respectively). Recommended for exploration, both versions *should not* be used for serious, normal, daily use. *They are too buggy and not production versions.* Backup regularly if you choose to use it that way.  On security updates, if any, check Glodroid's website
- There is a partition that may be created called 'vbmeta' which is created from a file 'vbmeta.img'. Don't know what it means when it is not created. Don't know what it's about. A cursory look on the net, android enthusiasts stackexchange in particular (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image) , seemed to show it can be created. Intructions for creating an *empty* file are below. Android (Glodroid in this case) seems to work without it anyway
- This worked for KDE Community edition 3GB model Beta edition with about 1 - 1.2 GB consumed and 2 GB to spare on a vanilla bare Android (Glodroid)
- Check PinePhone forums and Glodroid's Github release notes and issues page to see what works and what does not
- Looks very promising. Looking forward to an AOSP like LineageOS or GrapheneOS or /e/OS at some point or Remix OS (on a PinePhone!). Or maybe having it added to pboot multi-image. Yes, I'm hinting at some (maybe brave) soul out there... do something great!
- This was done on an Ubuntu-based system
- As of writing the files mentioned were downloaded around Nov 21 & Jul - Aug 21 respectively. They get updated and changed so might work differently later (hopefully for the better!). Downloaded from Glodroid's Github
  (https://github.com/GloDroid/glodroid_manifest/releases) ,
  (https://github.com/GloDroid/glodroid_device/blob/master/platform/tools/gensdimg.sh)

Instructions:

- Create a folder 'Glodroid' and change into it
- Extract Glodroid 0.7 (which is Android 12) compressed file into a subfolder, say, '0.7' for example. Likewise, for Glodroid 0.5.1 (which is Android 11) compressed file, extract the contents of the 'images' folder within it into a subfolder '0.5.1' for example
- Copy gensdimg.sh (see link above) into both subfolders
- Open terminal
- Change into the subfolder of interest, for example '0.7'
- Type and run 'gnome-disks &', which will run a Disk Manager Utility as a semi-independent process
- Plug in into the computer an EMPTY and CLEAN microSD card. IF THERE IS ANY DATA ON THIS CARD, IT WILL BE LOST WITH NO EASY OPPORTUNITY TO UNDO THE CHANGES
- Search using the disk utility and note the specific device for the microSD card, something like /dev/sdXX where 'XX' is some *device* letter of the microSD card on the computer. *Device* not drive letter - important not to confuse them
- now in the same terminal again, type and run a text editor, something like 'gedit ./gensdimg.sh &'
- In the editor delete as follows:

  - under '<<EOF', there is a list of single characters, mostly letters, ten in total. *To create 'vbmeta' leave as-is.* Otherwise, Delete the second last line of the list which has a 'w'
  - under 'echo "===> Add partitions"', there is a list with each line starting with 'add_part'. *To create 'vbmeta' leave as-is.* Otherwise, add to the second last line - containing 'vbmeta' - a '#' to 'add_part' to become '#add_part'. This will deactivate the line into a comment
  - (change only for Glodroid 0.5.1, leave as-is for Glodroid 0.7) search for 'boot' next to 'add_part boot.img' and edit it to 'boot_a'
  - save the edited file and close the text editor and back to terminal
- If 'vbmeta' is being created, an empty file 'vbmeta.img' needs to be prepared. At this point there is none. In terminal, run command 'truncate -s 5M vbmeta.img' which will create a 'vbmeta.img' file of 5 MB in size. To avoid potentially strange errors, in terminal run 'shred -zvn 0 vbmeta.img' which will write zeroes (000) throughout the file. The file is ready and has no data
- Run 'sudo ./gensdimg.sh /dev/sdXX' where 'XX' is the correct *device* letter for the microSD card
- './gensdimg.sh' will delete everything on the microSD card and begin writing partitions one after another, a process that can be seen on 'gnome-disks' opened earlier
- Wait for './gensdimg.sh' to finish but it should have several lines with 'The operation has completed successfully.'
- Eventually, it should come back to command prompt having ended with 'The operation has completed successfully.'
- Using 'gnome-disks' power off the microSD card to eject it and remove the microSD card from the computer
- Slot in the microSD Card into the microSD slot in the (already off) PinePhone and then switch on the PinePhone as normal
- One should see several images, an 'android' logo and eventually the Android 12 or Android 11 home screen. It can take several minutes on the first run

That's it. Thank your Maker you made it!